# How to determine which one is the directrix of the parabola?

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Given Focus S(-1, 1) and Vertex V(2, -3)

Now I have figured out two lines and those are

3x - 4y + 7 = 0

3x - 4y - 43 = 0

Now which on is the directrix.Please explain and also if there is any possible ways with graph and without graph to determine which one is the directrix.

Notice:Still haven't learnt vector and calculus.So I will not understand by those method

Comment: How did you get these two lines?

Comment: First I solved the slope for line of symmetry or axis which pass through those two point and then The symmetry line is perpendicular to the directrix.Which means that m for the directrix is 3/4.The focul lenght is 5.Now I applied the perpendicular distance formula from the vertex to the dirextrix.

Comment: You're almost done. One of the two lines passes through the focus, the other is the directrix

Comment: New to parabola. Wondering why I came up with two line.That was one of the best hint anyone ever given to me and I couldn't resist to say that.

Comment: Because given a point, a slope and a distance $d$, there are two parallel lines at distance $d$ from the point distant $2d$ from each other

Answer (score 1):

The directrix can be found by examining the distances of the line to the focus and the vertex. Note that the distance between the focus $S$ and the directrix is twice as the distance between the vertex $V$ and the directrix. Thus, we just need to check the distances between $S$ and $V$ and the two lines, respectively, using the distance formula below between the point $(p,q)$ and the line $ax+by+c=0$,

$$d=\frac{|pa+qb+c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$

The line $3x-4y-43=0$ is the directrix, because it has the distance 5 from the vertex $V(2,-3)$ calculated from,

$$\frac{|3\cdot 2-4(-3)-43|}{\sqrt{3^2+4^2}}=5$$

and the distance 10 from the focus $S(-1,1)$,

$$\frac{|3(-1)-4\cdot 1-43|}{\sqrt{3^2+4^2}}=10$$

i.e. twice as the distance to the vertex.

Answer (score 0):

The directrix of a parabola with focus $F$ and vertex $S$ is the perpendicular to the line $(FS)$ through the point $H$ which is symmetric to $F$ w.r.t. $S$. Therefore, you first have to find the coordinates of $H$. In vector terms:
$$H=F+2\overrightarrow{FV}.$$
Last, check which equation is satisfied by the coordinates of $H$.

Comment: Sorry Sir I still haven't learnt vector yet.

Comment: Didn't you see vectors in high school?

Comment: Things are different here.People barley know about vector and it's usage.Most of the time our teachers root learn it and encourage us to stay away from it.

Comment: In this case, you should know how to calculate the coordinates of the symmetric of a point w.r.t. another point. It's really very short.

Comment: Though your answer has inspired me to learn vector badly and able to understand is.It is a good encouragement.

Comment: Thank you for your kind appreciation!